# Why is script calculating Ellipsoidal area instead of cartesian area?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, ogr, features

I have this two shapefiles (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a83sh-V46uaoUFwPXEtoZnD_XUBGG9X9/view?usp=sharing). The original one is in 4326 reference system.
The second one is the result of qgis reproject processing.

I wish calculate the area (square meters) in each feature. This is my script:

```
# -*- Encoding: UTF-8 without BOM -*-

import ogr
from qgis.core import (
    QgsApplication,
    QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem
)

### CHANGE
dissolved_path = '/etc/zagros/20220223_Silvia_Jaqueline_RASTER/LITORAL_PR_CITYS_RASTER_EXT/ANTONINA/2000/0003_ANTONINA_PR_2000_DISSOLVED.shp'
reprojected_path = '/etc/zagros/20220223_Silvia_Jaqueline_RASTER/LITORAL_PR_CITYS_RASTER_EXT/ANTONINA/2000/0004_ANTONINA_PR_2000_REPROJECTED.shp'

import os
#  Initiating QGIS
os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM"] = "offscreen"

qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
qgs.initQgis()

import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins')
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing')

from processing.core import Processing

#  Initiate processing lib
process_obj = Processing.Processing()
process_obj.initialize()

standardAREAfield = "area"

utmzone = 22
epgs = 31982
# Parameters for qgis scripting
algorit = "native:reprojectlayer"
parameters = {'INPUT': dissolved_path,
              'TARGET_CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(epgs),
              'OPERATION': f'+proj=pipeline +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad +step +proj=utm +zone={utmzone} +south +ellps=GRS80',
              'OUTPUT': reprojected_path
              }

# Execute processing alg
Processing.processing.run(algOrName=algorit, parameters=parameters)

# Build driver
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")

# Open shapefile reprojected
datasource_reproject = driver.Open(reprojected_path, 1)

# Build layer from reproject dalyer
lyr_reprojected = datasource_reproject.GetLayer()

# Insert area field on attribute table
idfield = ogr.FieldDefn(standardAREAfield, ogr.OFTReal)

# Set field width
idfield.SetWidth(20)

# Set field precision
idfield.SetPrecision(2)

# Create the field on the layer
lyr_reprojected.CreateField(idfield)


for features in lyr_reprojected:
    # Feature Geometry object
    geom = features.GetGeometryRef()

    # Calculate area from geometry
    area = geom.Area()

    # Set area field with area value
    features.SetField(standardAREAfield, area)

    # Setting the features of this layer (final step, saving what i just wrote)
    lyr_reprojected.SetFeature(features)

    features.Destroy()

datasource_reproject.Destroy()
lyr_reprojected = None
```

The matter is the feature number 6 is a perfect square of 30 x 30 meters, so the area should be 900.00 m2... But this script is saving the value of 809.90.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found that feature from your files. The reprojected geometry from 0004_ANTONINA_PR_2000_REPROJECTED.shp is not square and the sides are not 30 m. The geometry as WKT is

```
POLYGON ((
        733451.619710086 7187073.450727058, 
        733478.7364326176 7187072.979020646, 
        733478.2170076868 7187043.121013427, 
        733451.1003455913 7187043.592723457, 
        733451.619710086 7187073.450727058
    ))
```

The cartesian lengths of the sides are about 29.8 m (N-S) and 27.2 m (W-E). The area 809.89 square meters is calculated correctly by cartesian coordinates.

It seems that reprojection of data does not happen like you supposed. The original EPSG:4326 geometry is

```
POLYGON ((
        -48.679076425737996 -25.41495635525268, 
        -48.67880693115276 -25.41495635525268, 
        -48.67880693115276 -25.415225849837917, 
        -48.679076425737996 -25.415225849837917, 
        -48.679076425737996 -25.41495635525268
    ))
```

Did you these coordinates as basis when you wrote that the sides are exactly 30 meters? How did you calculate that?

Comment: Those come from a landsat raster (satellite image) which has 30 x 30 m pixel. But i am sorry, you are alright, this image is a result of landsat image processing, it is not exactly 30 x 30 m (I just overlaped the original raster with the last output shapefile reprojected) and both are the same.